# How do I get my program to update the increment in the GUI window? (python 3)

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to create a program in a GUI window that tells the user to `press the button` and displays the amount of time the button has been pressed.  Here's what the window looks like:

[image: gui window]

The problem is that clicking the button is not affecting the number of presses, thus it always remains at 0.

Here's my code so far:

```
import tkinter

presses = 0

canHitEnter = True

def updateButtonPress():   #????????????????????? 
    global presses
    presses = presses + 1
    if going():
        pressesLabel.after(500, updateButtonPress)

def updateDisplay():
    global presses
    pressesLabel.config(text = 'PRESSES: ' + str(presses))
    empty.after(100, updateDisplay)


def going():
    global presses
    return True


def start(event):
    global canHitEnter
    if canHitEnter == False:
        pass
    else:
        updateButtonPress()
        canHitEnter = False



gui = tkinter.Tk()
gui.title('Press the Button')
gui.geometry('500x400')

startLabel = tkinter.Label(gui, text = 'press enter to start the game', font = 16)
startLabel.pack()

pressesLabel = tkinter.Label(gui, text = 'presses: ' + str(presses), font = 14)
pressesLabel.pack()

buttonLabel = tkinter.Button(gui, text = 'press', command = updateButtonPress)
buttonLabel.pack()

empty = tkinter.Label(gui, text = '_')
empty.pack()


gui.bind('<Return>', start)
gui.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why it's ignoring the `presses = presses + 1` part in `updatebuttonPress()`, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know that's what is being ignored?
Add a print there: "print presses"
Also, add a print in each of your routines, especially updateDisplay.  Make *sure* you know what gets executed.  You might consider the log_calls decorator.

Comment: when I put in "print(presses)" it prints in the shell, but I want it to show up in the GUI.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't ever calling your updateDisplay function to set the label to have the new value of the presses variable. Just call updateDisplay within your updateButtonPress function.